# How to write specific css top property for chrome, mozila

Tags: css

I write the css top for mozila and chrome.

```
    -moz-top : 20px;
    -webkit-top: 75px;
```

But it show me error "Unknown property name".

Comment: Why are you trying to give specific values for `top` to Webkit and Firefox? What problem are you having that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Vendor prefixes aren't for solving browser inconsistencies, they're for properties where the spec hasn't been finalized yet (eg. CSS3 properties).  Once the spec has been finalized, browsers are supposed to do away with the vendor prefixes on those properties and honor the unprefixed version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party but this did the trick for me:

```
/* this sets standard, which gets IE and others (all except chrome and mozilla) */ 

#EXAMPLE{
    top: -10px;
}

/* this gets mozilla */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #EXAMPLE{
        top: -10px;
    }
}

/* this gets chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
     #EXAMPLE{
     top: -5px !important;
    } 
}
```

Comment: And for those who say top: is handled the same by all browsers, I can most certainly tell you that it is not, especially when nested inside html5 table and li elements

Comment: IF YOU ARE USING THIS TECHNIQUE: please note that the cascading order is important, is it allows mozilla and chrome to override the previous #EXAMPLE selector style. Alter as you need with this in mind

Answer (score 1):

Just use `top`

It's supported by all browsers

Comment: but this is not browser-specific what OP wants

Comment: @dev-null-dweller what the OP is looking for is not possible.

Comment: @gargvipan if you're trying to set the `top` property differently for each browser, then you can try detecting the browser first, and then setting the property based on which browser you've detected